# Can I store timestamps in Central European Time (UTC+2)?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp-with-timezone, datastax-astra

I know Cassandra stores data in UTC time in a timestamp column but I need it to store the timestamp like the following (UTC+2, Central European Time):

```
2023-10-29 00:00:00.000000+0200
2023-10-29 01:00:00.000000+0200
2023-10-29 02:00:00.000000+0200
2023-10-29 02:00:00.000000+0100
...
2023-10-29 23:00:00.000000+0200
```

As you can see, there are 25 hours for the 29th of October 2023 and 23 hours in March 2023.

When transferred to Cassandra the timestamps above become:

```
2023-10-28 22:00:00.000000+0000
2023-10-28 23:00:00.000000+0000
2023-10-29 00:00:00.000000+0000
2023-10-29 01:00:00.000000+0000
...
2023-10-29 21:00:00.000000+0000
```

which is not the desired result.

Because I need to do queries when selecting the data, for example, `select * FROM series_op_test WHERE as_of='2022-09-30' AND name='LU_STC' AND time < '2023-10-30' AND time >= '2023-10-28';`.

And, if possible, I don't want to do any programmatically changes/conversion before or/and after selecting the data and when inserting the data through the API.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CQL `timestamp` data type is [encoded as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#timestamps) (Jan 1, 1970 00:00 GMT) so it is incorrect to say:

> ... Cassandra stores data in UTC time in a timestamp column ...

For example, `2023-10-29 00:00:00.000000+0200` (in CET) is encoded as `1698530400000` milliseconds. In cqlsh, it is displayed in UTC as:

```
2023-10-28 22:00:00.000000+0000
```

because it (cqlsh) defaults to displaying timestamps in UTC. You can override the default and [display timestamps in another timezone using the `pytz` library](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#pytz).

To answer your question directly, you cannot store the date/time "in CET" in a `timestamp` column but you can store timestamps in CET with `+0200` and it will be encoded to the equivalent milliseconds since epoch. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It does solve a bit my problem, as if I have a long time interval I have CET and CEST times, which can be encoded afterwards with +1000 and +2000 for example.